# How to make screen or component on top of other screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm making a music app and what I want to do is to implement a music player screen that can be active on all other screens something like this:
https://reactnativeexample.com/react-native-swipe-up-down-component/

This is my app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

import HomeScreen from './screens/home';
import SideBar from './screens/sidebar';
import SongScreen from './screens/song';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
    SongScreen: { screen: SongScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Drawer",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: why don't you use SwipeUpDown library?

Comment: You can use a custom component which is actually a `Modal`.

Comment: @sachin mathew SwipeUpDown library only appears on one screen :/

Comment: @AdamGold `Model` works but if i set the `transparent={true}` I cant interact with anything behind the model :/ how to change it's size?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a popup. I would recommend using [this library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel and make your root screen look like this:

```
<View>
 <AppContainer/>
 <SlidingUpPanel/>
</View
```

Comment: <AppContainer/> not rendering it's only SlidingUpPanel with nothing in the back :/

Comment: @Nameer you need to use my code like pattern. Try to add styles flex:1 to Views, or put SlidingUpPanel in other root component. I don't know why your code is not working